# How to get a variable added to the 'window'?

Tags: javascript, windows, qt

I'm adding the following code into the HTML of `QWebEngineVivew` page:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@widgetbot/crate@3' async defer>
window.obj = {}
obj.crate = new Crate({
     css: 
    `.embed
    {   
        min-width: 80%;
        min-height: 80%;
        margin: 0px;   
        background-color: transparent; 
        box-shadow: none;                
    }
    `,

    beta: true,

    indicator: true,
    server: '', 
    channel: ''
})
console.log(obj.crate)
</script>
```

I'm appending the value of `new Crate` to `window`, however, when I try to read it from the browser debug console (F12) it's undefined.

I also tested it outside of the `QtWebEngine` widget, at:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro

I get the error seen in the picture below `obj` not defined:

[image]

How i can add the value of `new Crate` somewhere to be able to read/modify it later?

Comment: you can not have a script tag with a source and code inside of it.

Comment: I can, the widget is working correctly, i just not getting her value using the window variable in the console.

Comment: Again, the issue is what I said.

Answer (score 0):

A script tag can not have a src and content inside the tag. You also have defer so either remove the defer like below or you need to run your script onload.

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@widgetbot/crate@3'></script>
<script>
window.obj = {}
obj.crate = new Crate({
     css: 
    `.embed
    {   
        min-width: 80%;
        min-height: 80%;
        margin: 0px;   
        background-color: transparent; 
        box-shadow: none;                
    }
    `,

    beta: true,

    indicator: true,
    server: '', 
    channel: ''
})
console.log(obj.crate)
</script>
```

Comment: Now the widget doesnt work anymore. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Crate is not defined`. The way i posted it work correctly i just can get the crate in the console.

Comment: A assume you did not remove the defer if that is the error you are getting. If you d not remove defer, you need use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { })` to set your variable.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to remove the `async defer` sorry, removing it obj is still undefined.